# How To Stretch Image Horizontally Full Width

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, fullscreen

I would just like the edges of my image to stretch the width of the screen. Not looking for it to be a full background.

My website is www.jobspark.ca

```
<div class="fullWidthSectionBG">
<div class="fullWidthSection">
<div class="myLeftColumn">        
<p>
</p> 
</div>
<div class="myRightColumn">
<h2>Used By Thousands Of Canadians</h2>
<p>Jobspark.ca is dedicated to providing resources for job seekers and employers throughout British Columbia and Alberta. Many top employers along with small local businesses from across the region post their jobs on Job Spark to find qualified professionals.</p>
<p>Job Spark simplifies your quest for the perfect career with a clean design and real-time postings. Our streamline job board was designed to take the headache out of finding a job.</p>
<p>Your job listings will be seen across multiple venues, receiving thousands of views each month! </p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.fullWidthSectionBG { 
background-image: url('http://static.squarespace.com/static/513d5347e4b0abff73be5264/t/519c45c4e4b084baf13d7e27/1369195972115/rocktruck2.jpg');
background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
height:575px;
margin-left: -1600px;
margin-right: -1600px;  
}
```

[image]